# On the etymology of Чубайс

Tags: этимология, ономастика

I'm curious about the origin of [Anatoly Borisovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Chubais)'s family name. Is it derived from Чуб? Or, perhaps, do Чубайс and Чуб have a common [origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/%C4%8Dub%D1%8A)? Is anything at all known about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling this name finds many web pages that claim that Chubais is a Latgalian surname referring to a "small, malicious house spirit". (Latgalians were a very small ethnic group that have assimilated with Latvians for the most part.) For example https://persona.rin.ru/view/f/0/11502/chubajs-anatolij-borisovich

> Фамилия **Чубайс** - латышского происхождения.
>
> The surname **Chubais** is of Latvian origin.

https://kompromatru.livejournal.com/1518260.html

> Чубайсы - выходцы из Прибалтики, и первоначально фамилия произносилась
> как Чубайтес. В Россию были приглашены Петром 1 , да так потом здесь и
> остались.
>
> Весьма интересна этимология фамилии Чубайс.
>
> Оказывается, у великороссов и латгальцев чубайс (чубысь, чубась,
> бесенок рыжий) - маленький зловредный домовой дух
>
> Chubais are from the Baltics, and the surname was originally
> pronounced Chubaites. They were invited to Russia by Peter I, and
> they stayed here.
>
> The etymology of the surname Chubais is very interesting.
>
> It turns out that among the Great Russians and Latgalians, chubais
> (chubys, chubas, red-haired imp) is a small, malicious house spirit

Also  https://russian7.ru/post/chubays-chto-na-samom-dele-oznachaet-yeta-f/ (in Russian) and many others.

However, some other web pages, for example, https://pikabu.ru/story/feyk_pyitayushchiysya_vyiglyadet_dokumentalno_podtverzhdennyim_7351753 (in Russian) ; http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3259379-chto-znachit-slovo-chubajs-v-slavjanskoj-mifologii-i-u-latgalcev.html say that this etymology is fake because some of these pages cite a dictionary that doesn't exist, and attribute it to a joke by the late comedian Zadornov.

I came across an interview with Igor Borisovich - Anatoly Borisovich's older brother. He said the following about their surname:

https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/2289207

> — Игорь Борисович, ваша фамилия какая-то нерусская, откуда ее корни?
>
> — Да, фамилия часто вызывает вопрос: белорусская она, еврейская или
> прибалтийская? Ее корни из Прибалтики, она искажена, в оригинале она
> звучала по-другому. Как — никто не знает. Есть разные варианты — и
> Чобатас, и Чубет. Но зато точно знаю, что все Чубайсы, все без
> исключения носители этой фамилии, — родственники. Мой троюродный брат
> специально исследовал этот вопрос. Однажды на конференции в
> Петрозаводске ко мне подошла женщина и представилась: г-жа Чубайс. Мы
> стали выяснять, и оказалось, что мы с ней дальние родственники. Это
> довольно редкая фамилия, она досталась мне от отца.
>
> - Igor Borisovich, your surname is kind of non-Russian. What's its origin?
> - Yes, my surname often raises the question: is it Belarusian, Jewish or Baltic? Its roots are from the Baltics, it's distorted. The
>   original it sounded different. How, no one knows. There are different
>   variants - both Chobatas and Chubet. On the other hand, I know for
>   sure that all Chubais, all the bearers of this surname without exception,
>   are related. My second cousin specifically researched this issue.
>   Once, at a conference in Petrozavodsk, a woman came up to me and
>   introduced herself as Mrs. Chubais. We started looking into it, and it turned
>   out that we were distant relatives. This is a rather rare surname — I
>   inherited it from my father.

Comment: Fascinating. Chubais is a bit like Pyotr Aven, then.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you start looking into Russian Federation nomenclature you will find out they're universally a bit like Chubais in this regard.